# Get the list of all content types

Tags: nodes, 8

How do I get a list of all the content types defined in a Drupal 8 site?

In Drupal 7 it used to be `node_type_get_types()`, but it has been deprecated.

I tried `Entity::loadMultiple()` but it doesn't seem to work. I was thinking about making a custom query, but I don't know how it's stored in the database.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`loadMultiple()` should be fine for this:

```
$types = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('node_type')
  ->loadMultiple();
```

Comment: Not working on  Drupal 8.9.x. Use https://stackoverflow.com/a/38252706/195812 instead

Comment: This still works fine in Drupal 8.9 @augusto. The other post you’ve linked to is not the same question - this is for loading the node type config entities, not nodes.

Answer (score 20):

You can load all of the NodeType entities (config entities) using the NodeType class:

```
$node_types = \Drupal\node\Entity\NodeType::loadMultiple();
// If you need to display them in a drop down:
$options = [];
foreach ($node_types as $node_type) {
  $options[$node_type->id()] = $node_type->label();
}
```

Comment: The trick with the static `loadMultiple()`, `load()`, and `create()` methods is to call them on the entity type class that you want to use, then it figures out the type and uses does the above dynamically. This is a bit shorter and easier to use, but it's recommended to use injected services when possible, so in a service/controller/plugin, you'd inject the entity type manager and then use that. Allows for easier (unit) testing but the result is more or less the same.

Answer (score 3):

There is another Drupal helper function that is not deprecated as of 8.7. `node_type_get_names()` returns:

> string[] An array of node type labels, keyed by the node type name.

[API docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_type_get_names/8.8.x)

Comment: This is the easiest solution if you need to fill form select (or checkboxes) options.

Answer (score 1):

Provided in case `node_type_get_names()` gets deprecated in the future (also a nice example of `array_map` usage):

```
function node_type_get_names() {
  return array_map(function ($bundle_info) {
    return $bundle_info['label'];
  }, \Drupal::service('entity_type.bundle.info')
    ->getBundleInfo('node'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a service for that called "entity_type.bundle.info":

```
>>> $bi = \Drupal::service('entity_type.bundle.info');
=> Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeBundleInfo {#1433
     +"_serviceId": "entity_type.bundle.info",
   }
>>> $bi->getBundleInfo('node');
=> [
     "article" => [
       "label" => "Article",
       "translatable" => false,
     ],
.
```