# How can I get a list of content by contentType?

Tags: 8, nodes

I created my content type Programmatically ..
I need a function that list content who have my ContentType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this

```
$types = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
->getStorage('node_type')
->loadMultiple();
```

More info [Get all node types in Drupal 8](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199852/get-all-node-types-in-drupal-8)