# Get all commerce product types

Tags: 8, commerce

I am creating a module that needs to add a number of fields to all commerce product types. 
In Drupal 7, I used the function commerce_product_types() to get all the types and than used that, but I can't seem to find the equialent in Drupal 8. So, I have commerce product type 'default', but I also have 'radios', and 'computers'. I don't know how many types there will be on the website, so it needs to automatically detect all types.

Comment: Use the entityTypeManager service to get them all

Comment: Could you please give an example?

Comment: See [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/199853/633) but use the entity type `commerce_product_type`.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
/**
* Get all product types
* @return array
*/
public function getProductTypes() {
   $product_types = \Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\ProductType::loadMultiple();
   return array_keys($product_types);
}
```

Comment: Yes, And for getting all variation types use `\Entity\ProductVariationTypes:loadMultiple`

Comment: `$product_types = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('commerce_product_type')->loadMultiple();`