# Color palettes for content types

Tags: 8, theming

We would like to give admin users of a custom theme the ability to set a color palette for each content-type for all visitors to a site.

The color module gives a way to allow admin users some control of a single color palette for the whole website but we want to let them set a palette for each content type (or leave the base color theme for each). Including any new content types, they may create in the future.

Is this feasible?

I have been poking around the color module but I am not sure how hard it would be to write a custom module that extended it in this way. Any ideas if this is even possible?

This is for a Drupal 8 site and theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this after 5 seconds of googling:

- https://www.drupal.org/project/color_field
- https://www.drupal.org/project/colorfield
- https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_colorpicker

The search query was: drupal color field.

---

1. Choose one,
2. add one color field per content type to the user entity type (users should be able to edit their profile),
3. then retrieve the current user and the selected values and add them as node class via [`template_preprocess_node`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/8.2.x).

---

> I may have been unclear. I don't want to let each user set their own
>   color palette, I want users with the right permissions to be able to
>   set the palette for an arbitrary content type for ALL users/anonymous
>   users accessing the site. (I'll update my question) – tanbog

For that you need to create a configuration form. @see docs [Working with Configuration Forms](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/configuration-api/working-with-configuration-forms).

You can get a list of all content types to build your form. @see question [Get the list of all content types](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/199852/15055).

You also may want to use the `color` FormElement. @see docs [`class Color`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Color.php/class/Color/8.2.x).

In the end you probably still use `template_preprocess_node`, to get the stored config in there, and then set the CSS class according the current node type.

Comment: I may have been unclear. I don't want to let each user set their own color palette, I want users with the right permissions to be able to set the palette for an arbitrary content type for ALL users/anonymous users accessing the site. (I'll update my question)

Comment: @tanbog – Updated answer.